# How to pass data between UITabBar views when switching over?

Tags: ios, uiview, uitabbar

I have 3 UITabBar items controlling 3 UIViews. One of them is a setting view named A, I set some values in this view and pass the value entered to another view named B. Now I already have the Delegate method but I use a button to pass the data. Now I want to pass it automatically when I select the UITabBar item of View B. Just from A to B, not mutual. Thank you.

Comment: using singleton class,its hope for you

Comment: If you already have a delegate, what is the problem?

Comment: Yes. I don't want to pass the data using button.What I want is Just enter the values and I tap a tabbar item of view B, the data will be automatically transmitted.

Comment: See my answer, Delegates shouldn't be used for this type of 'sharing'.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use NSUserDefaults. I have passed the string from one view to another

Below is the code you should write in DidLoad() method of ViewController A

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:@"xyz" forKey:@"name"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Code to be written in DidLoad() method of ViewController B

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *temp = [defaults valueForKey:@"name"]; 
NSLog(@"temp == %@",temp);
```

Comment: can I just use viewwilldisappear delegate and execute the methods?

Comment: Edited my question. You need to write the code in DidLoad() method

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of

> Singletons

They are used to share data between classes in Obj-c. For a guide on how to set them up see:

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

This will help to keep your classes separate and enforce an OO approach to sharing your data.

EDIT:

I found that site from a quick google search, there are a plethora of resources out there that will help you with this.

Comment: Have you seen the comments on the linked guide? "Singletons are the OO equivalent of global variables and all that entails." Or "Singletons are globals and should be avoided as much as possible. They create direct implementation dependencies and can be a nightmare when it comes to unit testing."

Answer (score -2):

Try This

```
NSArray *viewControllers = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
ViewControllerB *b = viewControllers[1];
b.yourValue = yourValue;
```